# mvc4 new { vs new object{

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am learning MVC (MVC4) for the first time and completing the MvcMusicStore tutorial from http://www.asp.net/mvc

The tutorial is written for MVC 3 and as I am writing the following code (in my MVC4 project)

`@Html.ActionLink(album.Title, "Details", new { id = album.AlbumId })`

visual studio is automatically inserting 'object' after I type `new {` to give me:

`@Html.ActionLink(album.Title, "Details", new object{ id = album.AlbumId })`

Is one way more correct than the other or is it a difference in MVC versions to have more defined code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The syntax

```
new object{ id = album.AlbumId }
```

should yield a compiler error because "id" is not a property of *object*.

The syntax

```
new { id = album.AlbumId }
```

is correct.  It creates an [anonymous type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx) with a property called *id*

Note that in a view, you will *not* get a compiler error at *compile time* (counter-intuitive as that may seem).  The view is compiled at *runtime*.  You may see a red squiggle under the error in the view's source code indicating a problem, but I have found that to work only sometimes.

I have seen the same problem with Visual Studio injecting an incorrect *object* after *new*.

Comment: I've been deleting the `object` but I can definitely see that error occurring should I have left `object` there. so this is nothing to do with a difference in MVC versions and more to do with visual studio jumping the gun when predicting data types?

Comment: @peroija: Yes, exactly.  It is annoying and hopefully will be fixed in an update soon.